# how to install blender older version(2.7) in ubuntu20.4

Tags: blenderkit

I need to install blender for my research work. Our software supports only 2.79 or below versions. So in the ubuntu 20.4 version, I can't install blender 2.79 or the below versions.

Comment: Why exactly can't you install 2.79 on your computer ?

Comment: @Gorgious when I started to install 2.79, the latest version will be installed.

Comment: Just download the version you need https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/ and unpack to a directory of your choice. Then run the blender executable from there.

Answer (score 0):

All blender versions can be downloaded from the blender website (https://www.blender.org/download/previous-versions/) including Ubuntu executables (not installation packages) that will run out of the box, provide all necessary software is already installed.

if you try running the executable, but it doesn’t work because of missing dependencies, you might try installing the latest version of blender with the package manager first. You would end up with two copies of blender, but you would definitely have all the necessary software to run blender.